# Effects of Active Virus Scanner on WebApp for XS Azure VM

Tags: performance, users, azure, virus

Suppose a public WebApp is hosted on an EXtra Small (XS) Azure Virtual Machine (VM).   What benefits and/or performance problems might visitors experience if a Memory-Resident Virus Scanner is run on that VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they would experience a detriment to response time relative to your VM resources. Beyond that its a guess question. "Some detriment, what specifically is unknown without VM environment specifics"

Lousy albeit concise answer. If you would like a more concrete answer: avail us to more concrete server resource information :D

Good luck sir or madam ! :D

Comment: Right now, the Azure Price calculator seems to imply that an XS Azure VM behaves like a 1GHZ GPU of unknown architecture with 768 MB of RAM.  The WebApp would be MVC and probably use few resources, but I might be tempted to load the XS VM down with an instance of SQL Server 2008 Express with no reporting services.  I’m wondering if I manually scan most of the content before making it publically available, do I really need the additional overhead of a Virus Scanner to protect visitors.

Comment: ok ambiguity question : "I'm wondering if I scan most WebApp content " --- do you mean "each request processed by the webapp" or is there some form of user submission process you are particularly interested in ?

Comment: If a user *legally* submits a picture or MP3 file to me that she/he created, then perhaps I can scan it on a workstation before allowing everyone else to access it on the server.  I would really like to avoid scanning every file access on the webserver via a modern day Virus Scanner since I *suspect* that would choke an XS Azure VM instance.

Comment: ok so the assumption at this point is your user's submission will interact with a servlet or something similar which will invoke validation methods / processes. With the assumption that you are using your own antivirus exam OR an external (3rd party) exam - the important part is to acknowledge to the user that the file has been received and is "being processed" (not much unlike Youtube's ) --- therein fork processing to a lesser priority and user experience is maintained as well as security. Threading is important to robust applications

Comment: I think you have a good point.  I would probably need to find an Anti-Virus product that allowed me to schedule the scan for a later time and then accept/reject the file.  Thanks for this tip.  If I perform a scan of the entire machine during off peak hours, and scan every content file before it is offered to the user, then I suppose the user is reasonably safe.  In this way, I can probably avoid the overhead of a Virus Scanner that might try to annoyingly run on every Web Request.

Comment: if you properly fork the processing of files, then you can additionally send the "confirmation" note to end users once the file is processed. In the case of an "image" that seems unnecessary - but if you are dealing with large files in varying formats - you should really just create a trigger to an antivirus application on submission of said file(s) and its actually quite lean on server resources (prioritization is key) .